# Escape single quote

Tags: sed

The following is working as expected. I want to replace the word "me" with \'

```
 echo "test ' this" | sed 's/'"'"'/me/g'
test me this
```

Expected result:

```
test \' this
```

Is it possible to escape double quotes as well in the same command?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing since there's no `me` in the original string to replace. However, I think I have it. Let me paraphrase:

> I have a `sed` command which can successfully replace a single quote `'` with the word `me`. I want a similar one which can replace it with the character sequence `\'`.

If that's the case (you just want to escape single quotes), you can use:

```
pax$ echo "test ' this" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"
test \' this
```

By using double quotes around the `sed` command, you remove the need to worry about embedded single quotes. You *do* have to then worry about escaping since the shell will absorb one level of escapes so that `sed` will see:

```
s/'/\'/g
```

which will convert `'` into `\'` as desired.

If you want a way to escape both single *and* double quotes with a single `sed`, it's probably easiest to provide multiple commands to `sed` so you can use the alternate quotes:

```
pax$ echo "Single '" 'and double "'
Single ' and double "

pax$ echo "Single '" 'and double "' | sed -e "s/'/\\\'/g" -e 's/"/\\"/g'
Single \' and double \"
```

If I've misunderstood your requirements, a few examples might help.

Comment: I think he meant a subsequent replacement for his first conversion.  
   
`[dod@MBP-13~] echo "test me this" | sed "s/me/\\\'/"`  


`test \' this`

Comment: @Dawn, actually I think that makes sense. OP knows how to do it to get `me`, they now want to do it to get `\'` (and for double quotes as well). Updated to (hopefully) answer that.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you could replace the outside single quotes to double quotes, worked great for me : )

Comment: If you want a way to escape both single *and* double quotes with a single `sed`, the best thing to do is just `sed -f mysedfile.sed`, and avoid the double-or-triple-escaping game entirely. This also opens the option of syntax-highlighting in your text-editor of choice.

Answer (score 14):

I have some doubts about your question, but anyway maybe my solution is useful for anyone.

Let's me say before all :

\\ that's mean one \ because when you put two together you are cancelling its meaning as metacharacter. And \x27 as single quote, at least for me is easier than working with single a double ...

Finally I put

```
echo "test me this" | sed 's/me/\\\x27/g'
```

so here you have   test me  ==>  test \' this

```
   echo "test \' this" | sed 's/\\\x27/me/g'
```

and here is the opposite.

Comment: I would never have figured this out by myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you mean?:

```
# cat <<! | sed 's/["'"'"']/\\&/g'
> quote '
> double quotes "
> quote ' double quotes "
> !
quote \'
double quotes \"
quote \' double quotes \"
```

Or this:

```
# echo "test me test"|sed 's/me/\\'"'"'/g'
test \' test
# echo "test me test"|sed 's/me/\\"/g'
test \" test
```

I find it best to always single quote sed/awk/perl... commands on the command line and make "holes" for double quote parameters used within them.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use '  in a script to create a dnsmasq config file, this is the technique I used:

```
echo -e "\toption name *$name*"|sed s/*/\'/g
```

example output

```
option name 'GarageDoor'
```