# sed replacing single quotes with backslash single quote for openssl config file

Tags: sed, openssl

The context of the problem is that i am trying to pass passphrases that have single quotes in them to the input_password parameter of an openssl configuration file.

Taken from [openssl configuration file manual](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/config.html):

> It is possible to escape certain characters by using any kind of quote
>   or the \ character. By making the last character of a line a \ a value
>   string can be spread across multiple lines. In addition the sequences
>   \n, \r, \b and \t are recognized

I assumed that single quotes can be escaped. The problem is i am having difficulty producing escaped single quotes with sed.

With this, i mean that the following expressions do not yield the same results if ran from a script or from the command line. Take the following commands:

```
cut -d: -f2 "$EMPLOYEE_CREDENTIALS_FILE"| sed -e "s|'|\\\'|g"
```

Where "$EMPLOYEE_CREDENTIALS_FILE" is a file with formated like

```
username:password
```

When i run this command directly in bash it produces the output i assumed openssl.conf tolerates:

```
tentacle caravan sovereignty appraisal sass\'s
```

And when i run it in the script it just produces the normal unescaped passphrase:

```
tentacle caravan sovereignty appraisal sass's
```

I would like to know what is it that i am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems pretty clear what the question is. "I have a problem trying to pass passphrases that have single quotes in them to the input_password parameter of an openssl configuration file." and i came up with a solution which is not working. So the answer should either correct the commands to allow the escaping to happen or offer an alternative way to deal with passphrases with single quotes in them. I don't know if i can be clearer.

Comment: I "think" because the documentation doesn't clearly state if the single quotes can be escaped:
"It is possible to escape certain characters by using any kind of quote or the \ character. By making the last character of a line a \ a value string can be spread across multiple lines. In addition the sequences \n, \r, \b and \t are recognized" Taken from http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/config.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem.

I am now in a position to confirm that openssl configuration files allow escaped single quotes to appear in the *input_password* field. Not only that but the actual password used by openssl is unescaped as intended. An end user would never know that the password was escaped in the configuration file.

I had quite some trouble making sed work inside a script because double quotes, from what i understood, consume the backslashes but not the single quotes. On the other hand, single quotes don't consume the backslashes and because of that can't interpret escaped characters. This means i can't escape single quotes inside single quotes.

This took me to a solution

```
 cut -d: -f2 "$EMPLOYEE_CREDENTIALS_FILE"| sed -e "s|'|"'\\\'"'|g"
```

This is similar to the answer found in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990807/227990) but it doesn't work for my case.

The reason 3 backslashes are need are also found in the answer:

> By using double quotes around the sed command, you remove the need to
>   worry about embedded single quotes. You do have to then worry about
>   escaping since the shell will absorb one level of escapes.