# How to escape $ in sed over ssh command?

Tags: ssh, sed, escaping, dollar-sign

I am trying to create a patch that users can use to remotely edit a file in a pre-defined way using sed, and I could do this manually on each computer, but it would take a long time.

The line I am struggling with is as follows:

```
host=[hostname]
port=[portnum]
ssh -t $host -p $port "cp ~/file1 ~/file1.bak ; sed -i \"s/fcn1('param1', $2)\n/fcn2('param2'):$zoom\n/g\" ~/file1"
```

This makes a backup of file1 and then edits a line in the file.  I actually want to edit more than one line, but this line demonstrates the problems:
The command works, provided no $ signs are used within the sed command.

I have tried a number of ways of escaping these $ signs but cannot seem to find one that works.
I can use a . wildcard in the find, but obviously not in the replace string.

I would use single quotes for the sed command, in order to avoid expanding the $2, but single quotes are already used inside the command.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to overcome this problem?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You need to escape for every parsing run done on the string. I'm thinking at least 2 runs: one for the local shell, and one for the remote shell, so you'd need at LEAST `\\$2`, and probably `\\\\$2`.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks, that was my 1st thought, but I found [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990750/escape-single-quote using \\\$2. I tried from 0-4 backslashes, but eventually decided to use the . wildcard for the first $ to simplify matters & concentrate on the 2nd $, but still cannot replace with $ in the second string, I've tried escaping with up to four backslashes: 1 or 3 returns the error "zoom: Undefined variable"; 0 or 2 enacts sed, assuming $zoom is empty; 4 produces a backslash before the empty $zoom. I've even tried defining $zoom='$zoom' with up to four slashes with no success.

Comment: I found the solution - temporarily retreating up a shell to plant the $ character;
i.e. replace [$zoom] with [\"\\$\"zoom]
This works for the first example too, so I don't need a wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

This should work as well:

```
ssh -t $host -p $port "cp ~/file1 ~/file1.bak && sed -i \"s/fcn1('param1', \\\$2)/fcn2('param2'):\\\$zoom/g\" file1"
```

You need 3 back slashes as you have to escape the $ sign in the string passed in the remote bash to `sed`. And you have to escape that back slash and the $ sign when sending it over via `ssh`.