# How to add quote at the end of line by SED

Tags: sed

```
sed -i 's/$/\'/g' 
sed -i "s/$/\'/g"
```

How to escape both `$` and `'` by 1 command?

Comment: The second command seems to work fine. What's the issue?

Comment: It cannot escape "$", flagging illegal variable name.

Comment: @ChristianFritz is right, second command should work perfectly.

Comment: For the first line?`sed -i 's/$/'\''/g'` or `sed -i 's/$/'"'"'/g'`

Comment: This might help: [Escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990750/3776858) or [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24509214/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

To add a quote at the end of a line use

```
sed -i "s/$/'/g" file
sed -i 's/$/'"'"'/g' file
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUGpWF9FX10/XUnBxsZGQUk9MSlZiQskoQ6WUAJC/XR1JMn//wE).

If there are already single quotes, and you want to make sure there is single occurrence at the end of string use

```
sed -i "s/'*$/'/g" file
sed -i 's/'"'*"'$/'"'"'/g' file
```

See [this proof](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUGpWF9dS0VfXT9dScHGxkZBST0xKVldiQskpw6UU1LXUlJXAdFKQDXqyGr@/wcA).

To escape `$` and `'` chars use

```
sed -i "s/[\$']/\\\\&/g" file
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUGpWD86RkU9Vj8GCNT005UUbGxsFJSAQkr//wMA)

- `[\$']` - matches `$` (escaped as in double quotes it can be treated as a variable interpolation char) or `'`
- `\\\\&` - a backslash (need 4, that is literal 2 backslashes, it is special in the replacement), and `&` is the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use single quotes to start the sed script?

```
sed "s/$/'/"
```

The `/g` at the end means to apply everywhere it's found on each stream (line) - you don't need this since `$` is a special character indicating end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$/'\''/' file
```

Adds a single quote to the end of a line.

```
sed 's/\$/'\''/' file
```

Replaces a `$` by a single quote.

```
sed 's/\$$/'\''/' file
```

Replaces a `$` at the end of line by a single quote.

N.B. Surrounding sed commands by double quotes is fine for some interpolation but may return unexpected results.