# Add backslash before single and double quote

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to add backslash before single and double quote. The problem that I have is that I want to exclude triple quote.

What I did is as for now:

**for single quote:**

```
sed -e s/\'/\\\\\'/g test.txt > test1.txt
```

**for double quote:**

```
sed -e s/\"/\\\\\"/g test.txt > test1.txt
```

I have text like:

```
1,"""Some text XM'SD12X""","""Some text XM'SD12X""","""Auto " Moto " Some text"Some text"""
```

What I want is:

```
120,"""Some text\'SD12X""","""Some text XM\'SD12X""","""Auto \" Moto \" Some text\"Some text"""
```

Comment: This might help: [How to add quote at the end of line by SED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64398822/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `perl` is okay:

```
perl -pe 's/"{3}(*SKIP)(*F)|[\x27"]/\\$&/g'
```

- `"{3}(*SKIP)(*F)` don't change triple double quotes

  - use `(\x27{3}|"{3})(*SKIP)(*F)` if you shouldn't change triple single/double quotes
- `|[\x27"]` match single or double quotes
- `\\$&` prefix `\` to the matched portion

With sed, you can replace the triple quotes with newline character (since newline character cannot be present in pattern space for default line-by-line usage), then replace the single/double quote characters and then change newline characters back to triple quotes.

```
# assuming only triple double quotes are present
sed 's/"""/\n/g; s/[\x27"]/\\&/g; s/\n/"""/g'
```